# Is AuthenticatedSystem an open source RoR module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking at this github app, and they have a module named AuthenticatedSystem.

I googled and found a rdoc, but can't find the source code for the module.

Anyone heard of this?  I know there are other authentication modules out there, but I am looking to just learn from this one as it looks simple to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the AuthenticatedSystem module is part of the highly popular restful_authentication plugin:

http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication[link text](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication)
http://rubygems.org/gems/restful_authentication

I hope this helps!

Comment: so its possible to just use the authenticated_system.rb in your /lib directory and not the entire plugin?

Comment: No, authenticated_system is only part of restful_authentication.  The plugin also gives you test helpers, to simulate logging in as specific users, and the generator to create your user model with the needed fields.